# What's calling Admin Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app service running in Azure, and has been running very smoothly.  Recently, in the last week or so, I have been seeing dependency failures (404) in Application Insights showing a GET for "admin/functions" route.

The host URL is my app service, with that route along with api-version appended to the end as a query string.

what would be causing this?

the routes are:

{AppServiceHostUrl}/admin/functions?api-version=2018-11-01
{AppServiceHostUrl}/admin/host/synctriggers?api-version=2018-11-01

Comment: Is the rout like this `/admin/functions/{functionname}/keys`?

Comment: I have added the routes to the original question.

Comment: how should i handle these requests then?  Since my app service is not making the requests. Not sure how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Azure Function Admin API. This is the API description:[Admin API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Admin-API).

The route you showed is used to [Sync function triggers](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Admin-API#sync-function-triggers).

```
POST /admin/host/synctriggers/
```